# Relation between multiple models and comment model in Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 3 models:

- model 1 : `Article`
- model 2 : `Course`
- model 3 : `Episode`

All of them can have many comments.

How can I make a relation between these and the `Comment` model?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the Id in your Article, Course and Episode is of type `long`, in the Comment model, you can have something like this

```
public class Comment
{
    public long CommentId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    //Type to store Article, Course or Episode
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //TypeId to store the Id of the Article, Course or Episode
    public long TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

You can also change the `public string Type { get; set; }` into an enum to be more clear and understandable.